# Flutter how to print to printer in ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, printing

I'm making a function to print in android and ios with flutter.
I found `printing` while searching for a printing plugin.
I have implemented pdf creation and printing through examples in this plugin.
In Android, it was printed normally, but in IOS, an error occurred.

***Error***

[image]

I thought this was an issue with the widgets in the MaterialApp and CupertinoApp depending on the platform.

So I set the Widget according to the Platform.

***button widget***

```
Widget _wifiButton(BuildContext context){
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        width: this.size!.width,
        height: this.size!.height,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        child: Platform.isAndroid ? TextButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WifiPrint())
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            'W i - F i',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ) : CupertinoButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => WifiPrint()),
            );
          },
          child: Text(
            'W i - F i',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

***class WifiPrint***

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Platform.isAndroid
        ? MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: PdfPreview(
            build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, context),
          ),
        )
    )
        : CupertinoApp(
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: PdfPreview(
            build: (format) => _generatePdf(format, context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Uint8List> _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format,
      BuildContext context) async {
    final pdf = pdfWidget.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: true);

    //final String documentPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

    for (int nCount = 0; nCount < Provider.of<ScoreProvider>(context, listen: false).scoreImageList.length; nCount++) {
      final image = await imageFromAssetBundle('${Provider.of<ScoreProvider>(context, listen: false).scoreImageList[nCount]}');

      pdf.addPage(
          pdfWidget.Page(
              pageFormat: format,
              build: (pdfWidget.Context context) {
                return pdfWidget.Center(
                  child: pdfWidget.Padding(
                    padding: pdfWidget.EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: pdfWidget.Image(image, fit: pdfWidget.BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                );
              }
          )
      );
    }
    return pdf.save();
  }
```

But I got the same error. Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

wrap the DropdownButton with Material()
you could also assign pdf to a new document, then add to it.
example: final Document pdf = Document();

Answer (score 0):

***Solved***

```
Widget _wifiButton(BuildContext context){
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        width: this.size!.width,
        height: this.size!.height,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat.a4, context);
          },
          child: Text(
            'W i - F i',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.white
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

 _generatePdf(PdfPageFormat format,
      BuildContext context) async {
    final pdf = pdfWidget.Document(version: PdfVersion.pdf_1_5, compress: true);

    //final String documentPath = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

    for (int nCount = 0; nCount < Provider.of<ScoreProvider>(context, listen: false).scoreImageList.length; nCount++) {
      final image = await imageFromAssetBundle('${Provider.of<ScoreProvider>(context, listen: false).scoreImageList[nCount]}');

      pdf.addPage(
          pdfWidget.Page(
              pageFormat: format,
              build: (pdfWidget.Context context) {
                return pdfWidget.Center(
                  child: pdfWidget.Padding(
                    padding: pdfWidget.EdgeInsets.zero,
                    child: pdfWidget.Image(image, fit: pdfWidget.BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                );
              }
          )
      );
    }
    return pdf.save();
  }
```